# Only list marker details from database that are visible only in map bounds

Tags: javascript, laravel, leaflet, maps

I am developing a Leaflet map app where we can view and find people in need of essential help. Currently, my map app looks like this picture:

[image]

with markers and details of the markers beside the map. In this example, all markers are in map bounds.

How do I do so that when we pan the map to other places, the sidebar will only show the details of visible markers? Currently, I implement it so that it just lists all details and marker details stored in a database. The current code is like this:

```
<div class=" ">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h2>SOS Berhampiran</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="beneflist">
                <h3>Perlu Bantuan</h3>
                @foreach($beneficiary as $key => $data)
                    <div class="helpsquare">
                        <b style="font-size: 25px">{{$data->name}}</b><br>
                        {{$data->help_needed}}<br>
                        Jenis Bantuan: <b style="font-size: 20px">{{$data->help_type}}</b>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <div class="beneflist">
                <h3>Mahu Membantu</h3>
                @foreach($donor as $key => $data)
                    <div class="helpsquare">
                        <b style="font-size: 25px">{{$data->name}}</b><br>
                        {{$data->help_offered}}<br>
                        Jenis Bantuan: <b style="font-size: 20px">{{$data->help_type}}</b><br>
                        <a href=" " type="buttons" class="btn btn-success">Lihat Bantuan</a>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the js used to reiterate the table contents

```
<script>
        const beneficiary = [
                @foreach($beneficiary as $key => $data)
            [ "{{$data->lat}}" , "{{$data->lng}}" , "{{$data->name}}", "{{$data->help_type}}"],
            @endforeach
        ];

        const donor = [
                @foreach($donor as $key => $data)
            [ "{{$data->lat}}" , "{{$data->lng}}" , "{{$data->name}}", "{{$data->help_type}}"],
            @endforeach
        ];

    </script>
```

And this is the database table:

[image]